# Difficulty scraping web table - multiple nested classes

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, html-table

Am trying to scrape a table from a website, however am not sure if am able to correctly refer to the appropriate class.
Am attaching the screenshot and also the body extracted from BeautifulSoup.
Am i look at this wrongly, please excuse me, am very new to web scraping.

I need to extract the table that is present in the circled highlight, however not sure to how to traverse there.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example (MWE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [don't post images of your code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question). Looks like the desired data isn't there as the data is generated by javascript, which isn't supported by libraries like `requests`.

Comment: thanks @joni sorry for the inconvenience. Is there a way to pull data thats generated by javascript ? Seems i'll have to explore selenium instead of BeautifulSoup ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The webpage is loaded by JavaScript. So you can use selenium with bs4.

**An example with working solution:**

```
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
import time
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

webdriver_service = Service("./chromedriver") #Your chromedriver path
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=webdriver_service)
url = 'https://web.sensibull.com/option-chain?expiry=2022-08-25&tradingsymbol=NIFTY'
driver.get(url)
driver.maximize_window()
time.sleep(8)

soup=BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')

data = []
for row in soup.find_all('div',class_="rt-tr-group"):
    OI_change = row.select_one('div.rt-td:nth-child(1)').text
    OI_lakh =  row.select_one('div.rt-td:nth-child(2)').text
    LTP = row.select_one('div.rt-td:nth-child(3)').get_text(strip=True)

    data.append({
        'OI_change':OI_change,
        'OI_lakh':OI_lakh,
        'LTP':LTP
        })
    
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
    OI_change OI_lakh      LTP
0          -     0.1    1354.200%
1      -7.0%     1.4  1429.20+11%
2          -     0.2   1354.65+8%
3      -3.3%     0.8  1332.75+11%
4     -25.0%     0.0   1109.80-4%
..       ...     ...          ...
56    -21.2%     1.1     0.85-62%
57     -2.3%    59.5     0.95-58%
58    -10.9%     0.6     0.75-63%
59    -33.2%     6.2     0.65-70%
60    -26.1%     0.3     0.60-71%

[61 rows x 3 columns]
```

Comment: Hey thanks a lot @F.Hoque, Could you help me how this works, also how do i find my chrome driver path ?

Comment: Seems I'll first need to download the chromedriver from http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html ?

Comment: At first you have to update your chrome browser if needed because your chrome                                        browser and chromwebdriver must be the same version. Keep the chromedriver using drag and drop and the script file in the same folder. Download driver according to your system:https://sites.google.com/chromium.org/driver/